# How to bulk prioritize Folder Syncing in Dropbox on OSX

Tags: macos, sync, dropbox, priority

I'm using Dropbox on a MacBook to sync folders with another user. Often, I need to quickly prioritize syncing a specific folder, but currently, I can only select "Sync Next" for individual files, which is impractical for folders with thousands of files.

Is anyone aware of any way to extend Dropbox's functionality to apply "Sync Next" to an entire folder? Can I programmatically set "Sync Next" for all files in a folder somehow?

Attempts:

- I tried using Applescript and Automator to automate selecting "Sync Next" for each file in a folder, but I'm unable to consistently access the context menu for a selected item in Finder. Moreover, any user interruptions break this approach entirely.
- I'm trying a scrape-style method to mimic Dropbox's background process for prioritizing files, but again don't think this would be a stable or dependable solution even if I do get it working.

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!